# JavaScript - How to remove all letters from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, arrayofarrays

I'm new on JavaScript and I'm trying to remove an array of the array if there is a letter

Ex: [["x","y", 2],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9],["a", 1]]

The expected output would be: `[[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]]`;

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Would the first array (now empty) be removed, or would an empty array remain in the result? Please include what the expected output would be for your example `data`.

Comment: Never use same index in `inner` and `outer` loops

Comment: Your two issues, as I see them: You're using `i` where you may have meant to use `j` in the inner loop declaration. Second, you can't do `indexOf` on a number, so your data will fail once it gets to the `2`.

Comment: What if the given array is `[["y","x",2],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]]`

Comment: Also, what about a numeric string, e.g. `["4"]`? Does that get included? Parsed? Filtered out?

Comment: @TylerRoper the array would be removed, and there aren't numeric strings

Comment: And what would happend if `arr = [["y","x",2],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]]`

Comment: Sorry, if there is any letter in the first array it would be removed so if it's [["y","x",2],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]] it would return [[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I think the problem is inner loop. Because `data[i][j]` will `"x","y",2,4,5...` and you can't apply `indexOf()` to numbers so it throws error.

You can use use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) inside [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)

```js
var data = [["y","x",2],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]]
let res = data.filter(x => x.every(x =>!isNaN(x)));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Code Maniac You are right OP question doesnot match because 1)his expected output removes the elements 2)He is using some thing like `[\p{IsLatin}\s]+` which he didn't told about

Comment: Yeah that's why it was a side note mate :) anyways just cleaning my comments as OP has already provided more clarification in question so they are now irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons:

1. You're using `i` instead of `j` in the inner loop declaration
2. You're attempting to do `indexOf()` on a number

Your desired output leaves a few minor uncertainties, but here's a solution using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) and [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var data = [["a","b",1,2],["y", "x"],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9]];

var result = data.filter(group => group.every(item => !isNaN(item)));
console.log(result);
```

**EDIT:** Updated code to address this comment:

> if there is any letter in the first array it would be removed

Comment: Thank you very much. You were very helpful.

Comment: @jordirigau Thanks, granted with your update, `reduce()` isn't necessary. I was updating my answer but saw Maheer was a step ahead - consider his solution instead!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result with single loop, use filter and Math.max, if array contains string, it returns NaN for Math.max

```js
var data =  [["x","y", 2],[2, 4],[5, 3],[6, 9],["a", 1]];

console.log(data.filter(v => !isNaN(Math.max.apply(Math, v))));
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zbRbob?editors=1010